# Is possible manage Error globally in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, rest, logging, error-handling

I need to catch Error (not Exception) in all Rest Controllers of my Spring Boot Application for logging purpose.
I would not like to add try.. catch block to all methods and manage this types of Throwable like I did with Exception that is using @ExceptionHandler annotation.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Component
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CoreExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler
    public void handleException(Exception ex) {
        //log exception
    }
}
```

Is possibile? What is the best way?

Comment: Not really sure. Although `Error` is also a `Throwable` just like `Exception`, maybe the `@ExceptionHandler` works only for `Exceptions`. I would say to give it a try, but looking at the `@ExceptionHandler` documentation it clearly states "An exception argument: declared as a general Exception or as a more specific exception.". So I guess it will not work.

Comment: I sure it doesn't work for Error, then I am looking for an alternative...

Comment: Remove `@Component` annotation. Also, best to have separate methods to handle different kind of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution and it seems to work:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CoreExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler
    public void handleThrowable(Throwable tr, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        if(tr.getCause() instanceof Error) {
            //log Error
        }
        if(tr.getCause() instanceof Exception) {
            //log Exception
        }
    }
}
```